# Stop waiting for the rest of a normal mode command and accept the command typed so far

Tags: key-bindings

I have a mapping for `m` and a mapping for `m/` in the same buffer, in Normal mode.

If I type `m`, is there a way to tell Vim to stop waiting for the 2nd character, and to just submit the current command as-typed?

I don't want to shorten the timeout or change any other "global" behavior. I just want to have the ability to tell Vim to stop waiting for more input and accept the current command.

Comment: Are you saying you do not want to use the mapping `m/` at all? Why not just unmap it?

Comment: @Mass I want to be able to selectively tell Vim not to wait for other keys in any particular sequence of key presses, not _every_ sequence of key presses.

Comment: There's no such operation. Your best bet is probably to reduce the time Vim waits for you to press another key before accepting the key(s) you've already pressed.

Comment: Possibly use the `<nowait>` modifier. But I am not sure, your `m/` mapping will then still work.

Comment: That's too bad @BLayer. It would be a nice piece of additional functionality, it could enable a different style of key mappings from what we typically have, you wouldn't have to worry as much about clashing prefixes.

Comment: My suggestion is to map to `mm` instead of `m`  so there's no ambiguity.

Comment: That's a good workaround @Biggybi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be impossible in general using standard key mappings. There is no functionality to tell Vim to "accept whatever I already entered" for an arbitrary sequence of inputs, at the user's discretion (i.e. without baking it into a key mapping with `<nowait>` or changing the timeout).

Answer (score 0):

The existence of the `m/` mapping REQUIRES that the `m` mapping needs to wait for the possibility of hitting the `/` key before the timeout expires.

There's no way around it.  If you want the `m` mapping to immediately execute, then it makes no sense to also expect `m/` to do anything.

Vim will immediately accept whatever you already entered if what you've already entered is unambiguous.   You need to eliminate the `m/` mapping to make your `m` mapping unambiguous.

Another alternative is to change your `m` mapping to include a second character.  Hitting two characters can faster than waiting for the timeout.